# what is the correct configuration of mod_ping on ejabberd-18.12.1?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am using ejabberd server `version 18.12.1` with stream management enabled. When the user disconnects from the internet, its presence remains online so I decided to use `mod_ping` to kill the connection after a timeout using mod ping

I used the following config in `ejabberd.yml` file :

```
mod_ping:
 send_pings: true
 ping_ack_timeout: 32
 timeout_action: kill
```

considering the default value of `ping_interval` : 60.

Ping does not seem to be working with this configuration. Am I missing any other configuration ? should the client enable something to make this working ? is there any ping log that I can check?

**Note**: using the modules page of the web admin of ejabberd server, the config value of the `ping_ack_timeout` of `mod_ping` seems to be different from the one in the `ejabberd.yml` file, why is that?

```
[{ping_interval,60},
{ping_ack_timeout,32000},
{send_pings,true},
{timeout_action,kill}]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Note: using the modules page of the web admin of ejabberd server, the config value of the ping_ack_timeout of mod_ping seems to be different from the one in the ejabberd.yml file, why is that?

That is expected: you set the human-configurable option in seconds, and later the internal time value is expressed in milliseconds (the time unit used by erlang).

> Am I missing any other configuration ? should the client enable something to make this working ? is there any ping log that I can check?

That should be enough. Try with other clients, just to check if that affects in any way. I've installed ejabberd 18.12, configured like this:

```
loglevel: 5
...
  mod_ping:
   send_pings: true
   ping_interval: 10
   ping_ack_timeout: 15
   timeout_action: kill
```

Then I start ejabberd and login with Tkaber client (but I think any client is good for testing ping). Every ten seconds, the client receives this query:

```
<iq to='user1@localhost/tka1'
    from='user1@localhost'
    type='get'
    id='rr-1552642185584-13814872912241253802-5xOvCCobbU2TCC/RT4GaqD6M8bo=-55238004'>
  <ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/>
</iq>
```

And at the same time, the ejabberd log file shows several messages, starting with this one:

```
10:29:30.585 [debug] route:
#iq{id = <<"rr-1552642185584-13814872912241253802-5xOvCCobbU2TCC/RT4GaqD6M8bo=-55238004">>,
    type = get,lang = <<>>,
    from = #jid{user = <<"user1">>,server = <<"localhost">>,resource = <<>>,
                luser = <<"user1">>,lserver = <<"localhost">>,
                lresource = <<>>},
    to = #jid{user = <<"user1">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
              resource = <<"tka1">>,luser = <<"user1">>,
              lserver = <<"localhost">>,lresource = <<"tka1">>},
    sub_els = [#ping{}],
    meta = #{}}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. After changing log level to 5 , I started to see the ping logs . I also managed to see ping messages received on my client and the client responding to the ping. the only missing part is that the server doesn't seem to kill the connection after ping timeout  and the other clients doesn't receive the unavailable presence status. The disconnected user remains online on the server . I tried Jitsi client and the user doesn't change to offline too after the ping time out.

Comment: @TareqAssi, I'm facing the same problem. How did you solve your problem? Did you get a quick disconnect?